# Blender 2.8 Face animation not rendering

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging, bones

So I followed a tutorial on how to rig and animate a face.  I did all the steps but when I try to render it I get a video of the face sitting still with no animation.  I have tried using Eevee, Cycles, and Workbench but none of them work. Here is the file https://www.mediafire.com/file/dkxx45nkp96xz8q/face_rig_set_upbone_testfinal_stepsanimationsetup.blend/file

Comment: It looks like that on my end, what should I see instead? https://i.imgur.com/iJXbmwk.gif

Comment: That is what it should look like. I can get it to play the animation in blender but I can’t render it out as s video. The animation doesn’t update. I just get a still image

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/r6bsh0j0gq013rz/bone_test_40001-5231.mkv/file

Comment: I tried baking the action into keyframes and all I got was this.

Comment: A friend of mine had a similar issue with his animation, but I could replicate the issue and after further testing we concluded it was a bug (the animation would render correctly only on single frame render but wasn't updating on sequence rendering). How you describe your issue makes me think it's somewhat similar, but since I can't reproduce it on my end... I'm not sure. Maybe try to append all your needed objects in a new clean .blend file and see what happens.